# Axios reload PDF content

Tags: laravel, axios

I need to reload a PDF file inside an embed tag:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group" style="height: 500px">
            <label class="form-label">Certificado Previo</label>
            <embed id="pdfcontainer" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Axios JS function:

```
function reloadPrevPdf() {
    axios('/draft-copy.pdf/{{$draftCopy->id}}',{
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'blob'
    })
    .then(response => {
        const filepdf = new Blob(
            [response.data], 
            {type: 'application/pdf'});
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(filepdf);
        document.getElementById("pdfcontainer").setAttribute("src", fileURL);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

The route `/draft-copy.pdf/{{$draftCopy->id}}` returns a pdf file with *php fpdf*, the project runs on Laravel 5, but this code is not working, **someone have an idea to this work please?**

Answer (score -1):

I think arrayBuffer it is the correct response type

```
  axios('/draft-copy.pdf/{{$draftCopy->id}}',{
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'arrayBuffer'
})
```

Try that out.

Comment: because, creating new Blob it is recursive. You can avoid that way o trying this.